# Why isn't this lining up right with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I needed to put in a flyout menu real quick for a client. I didn't want to mess with the CSS or HTML as they have it styled without JS exactly how they want it and they just want me to add the JS. I just thought it'd be simple to set the inner `<ul>` to position absolute and then the top offset to be the top of the parent `<li>` but it's not working at all. not even close.

```
$(function(){       
    $('#snav-links > li > ul').css({
        display:'none',
        position:'absolute',
        background:'#00182E',
        left:$('#snav-links').width()+'px'
    })
    .parent().hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('ul').css({display:'block',top:$(this).offset().top+'px'})
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('ul').css({display:'none'})
        }
    );
});
```

Here is the page: http://www.nwcidisplays.com/_temp/

Hover over the left sidebar menu items Banner Stands and Truss Displays. You'll see how off it is. Im not sure how to fix it. Ideas?

Comment: Here's a fiddle to help the answerers to answer: http://jsfiddle.net/rEVwd/4/. I don't have more time to spend with it but might help the others along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit of you troubles is the anchors within `#snav-links > li`. They are floating and don't take up space withing the li-element. This will lead the li element to have  the minimal height and they are positioned way above the actual link.

Remove the float and set the parent to relative positioning and that's it: http://jsfiddle.net/rEVwd/6/.

You'll also have to tweak the margin or padding in the li-elements so that the end result will be the same as before.

Comment: Confirmed on the actual page by inspecting with Firebug. Removing the (float: left;) in (ul#snav-links li a) and adding (position: relative;) to (#sub-nav ul) now shows the 'proper' positioning for the li (Firebug shows it in the same location as a.slink)

Comment: Perfect :) fixed the entire thing with just a `.find('a').css({float:'none'})`

Answer (score 0):

If you set position of #snav-links > li element to relative then the nested absolute ul will be relative to that container.

So (top 0, left 0) for your ul will be the top corner of the LI.

```
$('#snav-links > li').css({
            position:'relative',    // magic here
        }.find(' > ul').css({
            display:'none',
            position:'absolute',
        background:'#00182E',
        top:0,
            left:$('#snav-links').width()+'px'
        }).end()  // end() will take to back to the last selector (ie. $('#snav-links > li'))
        .hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('ul').css({display:'block'})
            },
            function(){
                $(this).find('ul').css({display:'none'})
            }
        );
```

You might then need to adjust the top and left based on that menu size (i'm not sure how your menu looks like)

Comment: That's not enough here as the parent elements offset is way off the mark.

Comment: well, obviously you would need to adjust top/left based on the containing LI but I thought you could work out that bit yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect with FireBug the parent `li` is positioned quite a bit above the button. *(As Aleksi said, due to it being a floated element)* (The button shows up as `a.slink`, it's parent `li` is located above it) So when you're retrieving the offset of the `li`, you're getting that location.

So you could try using the `a.slink` instead as it's positioned where you want it.

Also, to position the left directly next to the button, you'll need the offset + width of `#snav-links`

```
$(function(){       
    $('#snav-links > li > ul').css({
        display:'none',
        position:'absolute',
        background:'#00182E',
        left:$('#snav-links').offset().left + $('#snav-links').outerWidth()+'px'
    })
    .parent().hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('ul').css({display:'block',top:$(this).find('a').offset().top+'px'})
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('ul').css({display:'none'})
        }
    );
});
```